# Can't extract [Object, object] values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am trying to get a value from an Object. One product looks like this:

```
{
'amount': '29290',
'orders': '2',
'pricePerUnit': '15.5'
}
```

And I need the `pricePerUnit`, I have tried doing `Object.values(product_buyPrice)` but it still says `[Object, object]` on my website, I have checked other threads and tried stuff on there but does not work. How do I extract `pricePerUnit` from `product_buyPrice` and `product_sellPrice`??

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
        $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root | tojson | safe }};
        (function () {
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/bprices",
            function(data) {
                var products = data.products;
                var table_body = document.createElement("tbody");
                $.each(products, function(index, product){
                    var product_name = product.id.toString();
                    var product_buyPrice = product.buy_price;
                    var product_sellPrice = product.sell_price;
                    var row = table_body.insertRow();
                    var name_cell = row.insertCell();
                    //console.log(product_buyPrice)
                    name_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_name));
                    var quantity_cell = row.insertCell();
                    quantity_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Object.values(product_buyPrice)));
                    var price_cell = row.insertCell();
                    price_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_sellPrice));
                })
                $("#products_table tbody").remove();
                $("#products_table").append(table_body);
            }
            );
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10000);
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: What is `product_buyPrice`? `product_sellPrice`? `Object.values` returns an array, so that's likely where `[object, object]` comes from. Without seeing a sample of the data you're getting, we would have to guess, as the current answer does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In below code snippet i have use `$.each` loop to iterate over your object array and extract required values .i.e:

```js
//your response
var products = [{
    "id": "Abc",
    "sell_price": [{
      "amount": '727',
      "pricePerUnit": '3.7',
      "orders": '1'
    }],
    "buy_price": [{
      'amount': '29290',
      'orders': '2',
      'pricePerUnit': '15.5'
    }],
  },
  {
    "id": "Xyz",
    "sell_price": [{
      "amount": '31392',
      "pricePerUnit": '13.3',
      "orders": '4'
    }],
    "buy_price": [{
      'amount': '29290',
      'orders': '2',
      'pricePerUnit': '15.5'
    }],
  }
];

//var products = data.products;
var table_body = document.createElement("tbody");
$.each(products, function(index, product) {
  var product_name = product.id.toString();
  //looping through buy_price array
  $.each(product.buy_price, function(index, product1) {
    var product_buyPrice = product1.pricePerUnit; //getting value
    //looping through sell_price array
    $.each(product.sell_price, function(index, product2) {
      var product_sellPrice = product2.pricePerUnit; //getting value
      var row = table_body.insertRow();
      var name_cell = row.insertCell();
      //console.log(product_buyPrice)
      name_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_name));
      var quantity_cell = row.insertCell();
      quantity_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_buyPrice));
      var price_cell = row.insertCell();
      price_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_sellPrice));
    });
  });
})
$("#products_table tbody").remove();
$("#products_table").append(table_body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products_table" border='1'>

</table>
```